# problem in writing a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Getting a problem in writing an sql query.
two tables:

```
1st: created patient table                        2nd: already created doc table
     patientid  patientname  docid  workstatus          docid  docname
      1          aaa          2          10               1      ggg
      2          bbb          2          20               2      hhh
      3          ccc          1          10               3      iii 
      4          ddd          3          10
      5          eee          3          20
      6          fff          2          10
```

expected output:

```
docname workstatus(10) workstatus(20)
ggg      1               0
hhh      2               1
iii      1               1
```

can also use temporary tables between the queries

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format this if you expect anyone to read it or respond to it.

Comment: If I had edit capability, I would edit the tables to look like tables.  @satwik, could you help here?

Comment: Format properly and avoid shortcuts (pblm). Refer to these guidelines before posting a question:  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: BTW patient name is an extremely poor choice for a column. What happens when you want to sort the names in a report in alphabetical order by Lastname, firstname (the most common sort choice for names). And you will get trash in this column like John Smith and  Smith, John or Smith, John, IV, or JOhn Smith III, or Smith IV, John and you won't be able to diplay the data in any consistent format. Always store all names in separate  firstname, middlename, lastname and suffix fields.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

Full working example

```
declare @patient as table(
patientID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
patientName varchar(25),
docID int,
workstatus smallint
)

declare @doc as table(
docID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
docname varchar(25)
)

insert into @patient
select 'aaa', 2, 10
union all
select 'bbb', 2, 20
union all
select 'ccc', 1, 10
union all
select 'ddd', 3, 10
union all
select 'eee', 3, 20
union all
select 'fff', 2, 10


insert into @doc
select 'ggg'
union all
select 'hhh'
union all
select 'iii'

select docname, 
      SUM(case when t1.workstatus = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [workstatus(10)],
      SUM(case when t1.workstatus = 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [workstatus(20)] 
    from @patient t1
    inner join @doc t2 on t1.docid=t2.docid
    GROUP BY docname
```

Comment: Thanks for help but its not showing anything in workstatus column

Comment: Hmmm.  Can I see your exact Query?

Comment: I just got this much and i asked to get the output like this as shown above and they asked me to use the temp tables

Comment: create table patients(patientid,patientname,doctorid,workflowstatus)



1     'john'     2     400
2     'steve'    2     370
3     'dave'     1     400
4     'yyyy'     3     400
5     'zzzz'     3     370
6     'dddd'     2     400




create table Doctor(doctorid,doctorname).

1   'ravi'
2   'kkk'
3   'ttt'


write a query to display

doctorname,totalpatientcount(workflowstatus=400),totalpatientcount(workflowstatus=370)

expected output:

'lll',1,0
'kkk',2,1
'ttt',1,1


Clue:try to think of using temporary tables in between your queries

Comment: This looks like homework.  I'm not sure what your prof meant by "try to think of using temp tables".  If the answer helped you learn, please mark it as correct!

Comment: exactly its a homework only....im just new to this technology and i just signed in to this community......

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  d.docname, 
        SUM(case when c.workstatus = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [WorkStatus(10)],
        SUM(case when c.workstatus = 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [WorkStatus(20)] 
from created_patient_table c
inner join already_created_doc_table d on c.docid=d.docid
group by d.docid,d.docname
```